# MongoDB: Swap values in array in sub document

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with about 6 million documents where each looks like the following:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5d2327409ac8bc0085f3e733"),
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "osm_id": "2956281",
    "code": 1500,
    "fclass": "building",
    "name": null,
    "type": "tower"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -0.0154288,
          51.4539007
        ],
        [
          -0.0153606,
          51.4540789
        ],
        [
          -0.0150739,
          51.4540339
        ],
        [
          -0.0151478,
          51.4538517
        ],
        [
          -0.0154288,
          51.4539007
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

The values in the coordinates array are pairs of lat/longs, but they're in the wrong order for my requirements so I need to switch them. I have written a script in JavaScript which iterates through the array and switches them but it's very slow as it operates on one document at a time.

Is there any way to do this with a more traditional bulk `update` call, which presumably would be much faster?

Comment: Did you try [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I haven't, but it's not clear to me how to achieve what I want with that method. The bit I'm struggling with is how to reference nested arrays of arbitrary length, and also how to swap values in an array, I'm starting to think it may only be possible with multiple queries bit even that isn't clear.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this with a single update. Up until mongo 4.2 there hasn't been a way of referencing existing document values while doing an update operation, so you're limited to regular update operators which don't handle cases like this. Would an aggregation with an $out into a separate collection work?

Comment: @willis I’d be grateful for answers that used several but a fixed amount of calls. My current solution uses one update call per document.

Comment: Aggregating into a separate collection should use a single call (perhaps a few if you then drop the initial collection and move it back). Alterantively, doing it in a bulk-write might speed things up a bit https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/